# Configuring swagger for spring boot app

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have following [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api) to configure swagger on my spring-boot app. Here is my `SwaggerConfig` class

```
package com.path.to.project.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Here is my **WebSecurityConfig** class

```
package com.path.to.project.config;

import com.path.to.project.jwt.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.path.to.project.jwt.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/sysadmin/**").hasRole("SYSADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/siteadmin/**").hasRole("SITEADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Custom JWT based security filter
        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

}
```

So when I run spring-boot application (i am using intellij to build and deploy on JBoss) I see following UI

[image: Swagger UI on local spring-boot app]

What I am missing here ?

Comment: Do you use JAR or WAR deployment? Where are your JS/CSS files located currently?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your CSS / JS isn't loading. I would check your browser log to see what URL is used to make the request and setup the httpSecurity to allow those resources to load similar to your existing security roles.

Comment: okay thanks for the hint. This could be because of my security configuration. I can add rules for `.css` and `.js` files but even if CSS/JS isn't loading, why doesn't **swagger** show me api  and its methods ? it has nothing to do with the `.css/js` ?

Comment: Just guessing but the default Swagger UI needs access to the swagger.json file from the server. If the `.css` and `.js` files aren't loading then I am guessing the swagger file isn't loading either.

Answer (score 0):

In WebSecurityConfig, add following rule

.antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", "/swagger-resources", "/configuration/security", "/swagger-ui.html", "/webjars/**").permitAll()

/v2/api-docs - This allow spring security to show api and its methods. You can identify the problem by monitoring network-traffic in firebug or chrome debug mode