# Configuring spring boot to allow certain filetypes.

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have this [question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058628/configuring-swagger-for-spring-boot-app/39059808#39059808) open. I need to know how can i allow spring-boot to allow `.css` and `.js` files for `swagger` to be loaded ?

Here is my `WebSecurityConfig.java` file

```
package com.path.to.project.config;

import com.path.to.project.jwt.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.path.to.project.jwt.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/sysadmin/**").hasRole("SYSADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/siteadmin/**").hasRole("SITEADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Custom JWT based security filter
        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you use JAR or WAR deployment? Where are your JS/CSS files located currently?

Comment: Every request not matching anything must be `authenticated` just add a rule for what you want (above the authenticated that is)

Answer (score 0):

Just permit all access to your `.css` and `.js` paths (as you already did this with `/register` and other paths)

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/v2/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll() //swagger ui files
                .antMatchers("/sysadmin/**").hasRole("SYSADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/siteadmin/**").hasRole("SITEADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        // Custom JWT based security filter
        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
```

Comment: the problem is i don't have any css/js directories. Its a rest api with no ui. the css/js are being served by swagger (not sure what their path is).

Comment: Try to add this: 
`.antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()`

Comment: If you are using springfox (from tutorial) then all ui stuff required by swagger should be served through webjars mapping (swagger ui stuff is delivered with springfox)